# Why aren't two arrays of different layout-compatible types themselves layout-compatible?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Provided that `struct A` and `struct B` are layout-compatible, why aren't `A[N]` and `B[N]` layout-compatible? What is the fundamental issue with it?

In the following example, accessing the first union member through the second one inside `ub()` results in undefined behavior. However, in `ok()` the behavior is well-defined.

```cpp
struct A { int i; }; // A and B are
struct B { int j; }; // layout-compatible

union C { A a;    B b;    };
union D { A a[3]; B b[3]; };

int ok() {
    C c { .a = 1 }; // ok, initialize c.a
    return c.b.j;   // ok, as if c.a.i were nominated
}

int ub() {
    D d { .a = { 1, 2, 3 } }; // ok, initialize d.a
    return d.b[0].j;          // UB, A[3] and B[3] are
                              // not layout-compatible
}
```

Excerpt from the standard, [[basic.types]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#11) (N4861, emphasis mine):

> Two types cv1 T1 and cv2 T2 are *layout-compatible* types if T1 and T2 are the **same type**, layout-compatible enumerations, or layout-compatible standard-layout **class types**.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_layout_compatible) also mentions this but doesn't go into details.

> Array type of layout-compatible but different element types (ignoring cv-qualification) are not layout-compatible, even if they are of equal length.

Comment: I think your `ok()` function is also Undefined Behavior since `c.b` is not the active union member when the `return` statement is invoked, `c.a` is the active member.  Type Punning via a union is ok in C but is UB in C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This appears to be [allowed](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#25).

Comment: What comes to mind is two structs being layout-compatible but having different alignment requirements.

Comment: @orlp Seems reasonable. Alignment is the first thing that comes to mind. Current [definition](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#22) of common initial sequence, however, allows such [monsters](https://godbolt.org/z/5GhBvu) with manually-aligned data members to be layout-compatible, that is crazy. Did I miss something..?

Comment: Layout-compatible/CIS is a C compatibility hack that punches a hole in the type system. C doesn't allow this case either.

Comment: @T.C.: The Standard wouldn't forbid implementations from assigning different sizes to `struct A` and `struct B` (though I don't think the authors imagined that any might do so), but in the absence of N1570 6.5p7, behavior would be defined, on implementations where the structures have the same size, by the transitive relation between the addresses of arrays, structures, and members   N1570 6.5p7 puts extra restrictions on what *strictly conforming* programs may do, but the Standard waives jurisdiction over what "merely" conforming programs may do, imposing essentially no restrictions upon them.